# How to implement stress/strain mechanics in voxel terrain?

Tags: physics, mathematics, game-mechanics, terrain, voxels

I am in the process of developing a Minecraft-like world where the terrain is divided into voxels. However, I would also like for unstable configurations of landscapes to collapse predictably. For example, [an overhang that is too heavy would fracture and break off at 'high stress' voxels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIFO1.png), as would [a pillar formation with an asymmetrically eroded base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ObVb.png). I was thinking about adding a 'stress vector' field to each voxel in the terrain, and doing the following (pseudocode):

```
foreach voxel in terrain
    foreach neighbor in voxel.neighbor_voxels()
        if magnitude(voxel.stress - neighbor.stress) > stressThreshold
            detach_voxels(voxel, neighbor)
```

But the problem is that I don't know how I would go about calculating these individual stresses. Is there some kind of FEA-based algorithm specialized for voxel discretizations that I can use to calculate the stresses on a per-voxel basis? Or am I approaching this all wrong and there's some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider a DFS search of all of the connected voxels and determine the voxel that is the single most depended on or "branched" from. And then run your nice little pseudo code. :)